# Как сказать остро, эффектно?

Tags: грамотная-речь

7. Как сказать о чем-то, что мозг с трудом способен воспринимать, что содержит многочисленные "нечеловеческие" сложности.

Это сложно, это сверхрационально, это нечеловечно. Недетская сложность. Стоит вывернуть мозги наизнанку, чтобы это понять.

Одним эффектным словом.

Answer (score 1):

Такое слово действительно существует, и оно очень крутое.
**Трансцендентный** — запредельный, находящийся за пределами опыта, недоступный познанию, непостижимый для разума.
*Бесконечность трансцендентна.*

Answer (score 0):

Можно сказать так: это ***запредельно, непостижимо, непознаваемо.***

Можно использовать для усиления эффекта весь ряд или придумать сложное слово (словосочетание), например: *запредельно-непостижимо*.

Answer (score 0):

Одним словом эффектно сложно сказать, лучше использовать фразеологизм: заумно так, что мозги кипят (мозги плавятся), голову сломаешь.

Неподвластно моему разуму.

Мозговыкручивание.